# How make case when in WHERE clause for MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I use a case when it works perfectly fine on MySQL but not MS SQL please help.

It seems the equal is not accepted -- if not what then will work

```
SELECT A FROM TABLE A
WHERE 
CASE WHEN COUNT = 2 THEN GOAL = 2 ELSE GOAL = 3 END
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'CASE'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query to `WHERE columnName = value`.

The following query is what you are expecting:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE A
WHERE GOAL = CASE WHEN COUNT = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: @ElectronicCircuit If it solves your problem, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)

Comment: how about if i want the result to have multiple? like GOAL = CASE WHEN  COUNT = 2 THEN 2,3, AND 4